# How to apply a list to a larger set

Tags: python, pandas, list

How can I apply a list of `x` names to a larger list of items of equal length (or dataframe rows)?

I have a dataframe of `x` rows and I need to apply a set of `y` names to the frame.  How can I go about assigning names to an equal length within the dataframe?

i.e. for a `df 10 rows` long and 3 names, would apply `name[0]` to `df row 0-3`; `name[1]` to `df 3-6`; and `names[2]` to `df 6-9`.

I can't user itertools cycle as I need this to be in order (`name[0]` to `df row 0-3`)

I know this is a simple task, simply can't get it into my head.  Thanks.

Comment: How can you divide 10 by 3 without remainder? I don't get it.

Comment: @Winand Using floor division?

Comment: @cs95 then chunks will have different lengths

Comment: Wasn't so simple after all.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with `labels=` argument:

> Bin values into discrete intervals. Use cut when you need to segment and sort data values into bins.
>
> labels : Specifies the labels for the returned
>   bins.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]})
l1 = "a", "b", "c"  # abc
df["B"] = pd.cut(range(len(df)), len(l1), labels=l1)
```

Comment: Winand, this won't work for any non-0 remainders as you mentioned above.  A ceil calc doesn't work as it calculates 10 rows as 4,4,2.  Looking for something that would create a list of length 3,3,(remainder)4 (or 4,3,3 if it's easier)

Comment: @JBeckford you can use `fillna` to fill missing values. See updated answer.

Comment: I was able to figure out the answer as below.  Fillna doesn't work as it won't assign an equal distribution.  i.e. 5 rows assigns a,b,c,c,c.

Comment: @JBeckford oh, now I understand your problem. See my updated answer. It's just an option, gives the same result as your example

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
l1 = ["a", "b", "c"]

dic = sorted(zip(df.A.index,itertools.cycle(l1)), key= lambda x: x[1])
df['B'] = [x[1] for x in dic]
```